# Laravel 5.1 Multitenancy setup

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.1 and have a multi-tenancy database setup using a `trait` and `scope` as below.  How can I add to this so that all insert queries also get the `cust_id` parameter injected?

**Scope:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ScopeInterface;
use App\Customers;
use DB, Session;

class MultiTenantScope implements ScopeInterface
{
    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  UsersRoles $roles
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->custId = Session::get('cust_id');
    }

    /**
     * Apply scope on the query.
     *
     * @param Builder $builder
     * @param Model $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        if($this->custId) 
        {
            $builder->where($model->getTable() . '.cust_id', $this->custId); 
        } 
        else 
        {
            $model = $builder->getModel();
            $builder->whereNull($model->getKeyName()); 
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove scope from the query.
     *
     * @param Builder $builder
     * @param Model $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function remove(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $query = $builder->getQuery();
        $query->wheres = collect($query->wheres)->reject(function ($where) 
        {
            return ($where['column'] == 'cust_id');
        })->values()->all();
    }  
}
```

**Trait:**

```
<?php 

namespace App\Scopes;

trait MultiTenantTrait
{
    /**
     * Boot the scope.
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public static function bootMultiTenantTrait()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new MultiTenantScope());
    }

    /**
     * Get all tenants.
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public static function allTenants()
    {
        return (new static())->newQueryWithoutScope(new MultiTenantScope());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do that, you'll need to override the default Eloquent Model's behaviour. You can modify one of the methods that participate in creating object or saving it.

My suggestion is to override the default creation behaviour logic as this will give you an object with **custId** set even before you save it to the database.

The easiest way to achieve that is to override the inherited constructor in a trait. In order to do that, add this method to your trait:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
  parent::__construct(array_merge($attributes, ['cust_id' => $this->custId]));
}
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for this but it results in the error: `MassAssignmentException in Model.php line 417: cust_id`.  Do I need to add cust_id somewhere else?

Comment: It needs to be in $fillable array

Comment: Just added it to $fillable but still the same error.

Comment: What verson of Laravel are you using? I'm looking at the code of 5.1 and the only case when this exception can be thrown is when the Model is totally guarderd, meaning "count($this->fillable) == 0 && $this->guarded == ['*']"

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.1

Comment: Where did you add the $fillable array? In the model, trait or the scope class?

Comment: Whoops! Missed $fillable on one table, so that error is gone now.  However, when I run a `create()` command, the cust_id is still not inserted.

Comment: Actually i'm using the insert() command, will this still add the `cust_id` attribute?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87056/discussion-between-jedrzej-kurylo-and-v4n1ll4).