# Run a query on every eloquent call to a certain model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

In Laravel 4.2, is it possible to add a condition that is automatically called, much like is_deleted is automatically checked for, but for only one model?

I could manually add these checks in, but there are several places where the same code would need to be written over and over again, and there are several people working in the project and the likelihood that someone would forget the check once is somewhat high, I would think.

While not completely necessary, I would prefer it with an option to disable the check, much like how withTrashed() works.

Comment: "it possible to add a condition that is automatically called" - could you elaborate on this? maybe some example, it's not unclear what automatic behaviour you mean

Comment: Items::where('id', '>', 5)->get();  For example when I do this, I want it to return only items that are also ->where('user_id','=',$user_id), however, seeing as literally every single call I'm doing to Items will require this call, I am wondering if there is a way to have it automatically be included, just as ->where('deleted_at','=',null) is included by the system automatically.

Comment: Ah, global scopes you mean, young padawan ;) I'll post an example in a second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Eloquent** provides one mechanism that allows applying selected operations on all queries that are run on given mode - global scopes. You can read about them in the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#global-scopes

Have a look at the example here: [Laravel 5.1 Multitenancy setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022783/laravel-5-1-multitenancy-setup/32023101#32023101)

It does exactly what you need - always adds one constraint on user_id to all queries that are run.